# Baking inside walls of a cube

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I'm doing my first interior scene. In the scene I'm using a cube as the room with a hole to let in some light. I'm using light portal. Every object in the scene bakes well apart from the cube which comes out all white. I have tried to use the backfacing option of the Geometric node but the results are the same. How do you bake the inside walls of a cube for faster rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your objects and go into *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and press <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice so your whole mesh is selected. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and select *Flip Normals*. What this does it flips the the direction of what *Blender* thinks is the outside layer.